# Table build with flex and divs with pinned column

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox, css-tables

I'm building table that should be fully responsive (so I'm using flex on divs instead of `table`).
I want to be able to pin column.

Here what I've got https://codepen.io/piernik/pen/LmoBxM

What's the problem?
When You scroll left pinned column disapears.
It's probably that `.row2` has width of viewport, not entire table.
You can see `.row2`'s width on the red top border.

Can I fix it?

I want to build responsive table with pinned column that can have hsrcoll without any JS.

Comment: The problem in your code isn't flexbox, it's `position: sticky`, which has [weak browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). Plus, on quick review, I'm not sure you've implemented it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You used flex-basis:500px in cell that's why your table width larger than windows width and flex cover only all window width.

Comment: How to fix it so `.row2` will cover whole width of that row? Not only visible?